# C++ Matrix class template inheritance

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance, matrix

I have recently started to code a Matrix class in c++. A matrix can be square or not. So I firstly created a Matrix base class template. Then, I wanted to implement a SquareMatrix class, to handle inversion and other similar stuff. But it obviously didnt work and I got the following errors :

### My code (working with GCC on codeblocks) :

Matrix.hpp:

```
template<unsigned int M, unsigned int N>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix() {}

    ...

private:
    std::vector<float> mElements;
};
```

SquareMatrix.hpp:

```
#include "Matrix.hpp"

template<unsigned int M>
class SquareMatrix: public Matrix<M, M>
{
    ...
};
```

### Build log :

```
||=== Build: Debug in KirchhofSolver (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
F:\Data\Programmation\KirchhoffSolver\SquareMatrix.hpp|7|error: expected template-name before '<' token|
F:\Data\Programmation\KirchhoffSolver\SquareMatrix.hpp|7|error: expected '{' before '<' token|
F:\Data\Programmation\KirchhoffSolver\SquareMatrix.hpp|7|error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

If you could help me, I'd be grateful, because I've already spent a long time browsing on internet for answers to my problem, and I couldnt find anything !

Comment: did you read error?

Comment: Besides the error, is there any particular reason why you want to use a template?

Comment: Yes I read the error, and searched for it, and I couldnt find, as I said. And I really want to use a template. Because I can inherit SquareMatrix from it but also Vector, abd I could multiply a SquareMatrix and a Vector, in the end, because their operators both come from Matrix.

Comment: This builds for me in MS visual studio 2015 - assuming a #include<vector> is added before its use in Matrix.hpp

Comment: Do you have an explanation for codeblocks not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Matrix class template that I worked on a little while back and this allows for MxN  as well as MxNxO matrices. I only have 2 methods other than the constructor and that is to set the matrix to zero and to generate the identity matrix. Maybe this can be of use to you, however I have not tried to "inherit" from this class.

```
#include <iostream>

// template<typename TYPE, X, Y, Z>
template<typename T, unsigned X, unsigned Y, unsigned Z = 1>
class Matrix {
public:
    const unsigned x_size = X;
    const unsigned y_size = Y; 
    const unsigned z_size = Z;
    T matrix_[X][Y][Z];

private:

    T identity_[X][Y][Z];

public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix( T elements[X][Y][Z] );

    void identity( T identity[X][Y][Z] );
    void matrix( T matrix[X][Y][Z] );

private:
    void zeroMatrix();
    void makeIdentity();

};

template<typename T, unsigned X, unsigned Y, unsigned Z>
Matrix<T, X, Y, Z>::Matrix() {
    zeroMatrix();
    makeIdentity();
}

template<typename T, unsigned X, unsigned Y, unsigned Z>
Matrix<T, X, Y, Z>::Matrix( T elements[X][Y][Z] ) {
    for ( unsigned k = 0; k < z_size; k++ ) {
        for ( unsigned j = 0; j < y_size; j++ ) {
            for ( unsigned i = 0; i < z_size; i++ ) {
                matrix_[i][j][k] = elements[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }
}

template<typename T, unsigned X, unsigned Y, unsigned Z>
void Matrix<T, X, Y, Z>::zeroMatrix() {
    for ( unsigned k = 0; k < z_size; k++ ) {
        for ( unsigned j = 0; j < y_size; j++ ) {
            for ( unsigned i = 0; i < x_size; i++ ) {
                matrix_[i][j][k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

template<typename T, unsigned X, unsigned Y, unsigned Z>
void Matrix<T, X, Y, Z>::matrix( T matrix[X][Y][Z] ) {
    for ( unsigned k = 0; k < z_size; k++ ) {
        for ( unsigned j = 0; j < y_size; j++ ) {
            for ( unsigned i = 0; i < x_size; i++ ) {
                matrix[i][j][k] = matrix_[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }
}

template<typename T, unsigned X, unsigned Y, unsigned Z>
void Matrix<T, X, Y, Z>::makeIdentity() {

    if ( z_size > 1 ) {
        for ( unsigned k = 0; k < z_size; k++ ) {
            for ( unsigned j = 0; j < y_size; j++ ) {
                for ( unsigned i = 0; i < x_size; i++ ) {
                    if ( i == j && i == k && j == k ) {
                        identity_[i][j][k] = 1;
                    } else {
                        identity_[i][j][k] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        for ( unsigned j = 0; j < y_size; j++ ) {
            for ( unsigned i = 0; i < x_size; i++ ) {
                if ( i == j ) {
                    identity_[i][j][0] = 1; 
                } else {
                    identity_[i][j][0] = 0;         
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

template<typename T, unsigned X, unsigned Y, unsigned Z>
void Matrix<T, X, Y, Z>::identity( T identity[X][Y][Z] ) {
    for ( unsigned k = 0; k < z_size; k++ ) {
        for ( unsigned j = 0; j < y_size; j++ ) {
            for ( unsigned i = 0; i < x_size; i++ ) {
                identity[i][j][k] = identity_[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    const int x = 4;
    const int y = 4;
    const int z = 4;

    // MxNxO      
    Matrix<int,x,y,z> a;

    int identity3D[x][y][z] = {0};
    a.identity( identity3D );

    std::cout << "MxNxO Matrix Identity of Integer Type: " << std::endl;
    for ( unsigned k = 0; k < z; k++ ) {
        for ( unsigned j = 0; j < y; j++ ) {        
            for ( unsigned i = 0; i < x; i++ ) {
            std::cout << identity3D[i][j][k] << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    // MxN Matrix Identity of Float Type - using last template argument with a value of 1.
    const int a = 3;
    const int b = 4;
    const int c = 1;
    Matrix<float,a,b,c> b;

    float idenity2D[a][b][c] = {0};  // Still Need To Use 3RD Array But Set to 1.
    std::cout << "MxN Matrix Identity of Float Type: " << std::endl;

    for ( unsigned k = 0; k < c; k++ ) {
        for ( unsigned j = 0; j < b; j++ ) {        
            for ( unsigned i = 0; i < a; i++ ) {
                std::cout << identity2D[i][j][k] << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

I haven't completely finished this class and my original thought of this type of matrix class was more of a storage class than a operational mathematical class or structure. I was designing this to store different types of objects from different numerical atomic types to classes, structures or even function pointers. I only added the "zero method" and "identity" functions to make sure I was constructing it correctly. However this does compile and run without error in MSVS2015CE on Windows 7 - x64. Feel free to use it, build upon it, improve it or even completely reject it.

Comment: Thank you that's fine ! But I would really like to understand what I did wrong, in order to progress and to learn things. When a problem occurs to me, I prefer solving it rather than taking the other's solution !

Comment: That is completely understandable, but I posted mine since I seen the similarities between the two. The only major differences are I'm storing them in an array as you are in a vector and mine will do a MxNxO as well as an MxN as yours will only do a MxN. The similarity between the two is that they are both class templates. You are trying to inherit from this in which I have not tried to as of yet, so I decided to post mine as well since it is relevant to the topic and your question for I'm also curious as to how to inherit from this as well.

Comment: That's also what interests me - knowing how to inherit from that class template !

Comment: Inheriting from class templates can be tricky because the one thing that a base class of a template type can not derive are some of the operator overloads more specifically the `operator=()` and I think the copy constructor. The reason for this is because `class<T> a;`  & `class<U> b;` are two different classes. It gets tricky and weird because of it.

Comment: Ok, but do you have an explanation for codeblocks not working, because, ROX (he answered above) could compile my code with VS 2015, and didnt get any error

Answer (score 0):

I will suicide, because that was simply a header declaration problem, nothing related to the code I showed you. So my problem is solved !